# Кракозябры при чтении и записи из текстового файла или Memo в blob и обратно

Tags: delphi, firebird

Есть бд на firebird3. Программа записывает данные из файла или из memo  в blob и обратно- читать из blob в мемо. 
В бд есть 2 блоб поля: **blob_Binary**(subtype=0) и **Blob_Text**(subtype=1,utf-8).
Кодировка и в строке подключения к базе и таблицы- Utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[смотрите Проект и БД](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T2KAJUQGhAePOJokQN2wlcn69mAFyABY)

Есть следующие проблемы сохранения русских и грузинских букв.

1) **сохранение данных в блоб из memo.**

Если так тогда **ничего** не сохраняется!!!:

```
var ms : TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  memo1.lines.savetostream(ms);
  ms.position := 0; 
  Query1.Close;
  Query1.SQL.Text:='insert into content(Blob_text) values(:Blob_text)';
  Query1.ParamByName('Blob_text').LoadFromStream(ms, ftunknown);
  Query1.ExecSQL;
finally
    ms.free;
end;
```

а с помощью **stringlist** в бинарном блоб-е неправильно сохраняется (Английские и русские тексты адекватно сохраняются, а вместо грузинских букв выводит вопросительные знаки)

> 111 Hello Привет ??????

```
var
sl :TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
try
  sl.Text := Memo1.Text;
  Query1.Edit;
  Query1.FieldByName('blob_Binary').Assign(sl);
  Query1.Post;
finally
  sl.Free;
end;
```

А если использовать стримы тогда тоже вместо грузинских букв вижу вопросительные знаки

```
var
  i:integer;
  blobF : TBlobField;
  ms : TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  memo1.lines.savetostream(ms);
  ms.position := 0;

  Query1.Edit;
  TBlobField(Query1.FieldByName('BLOB_BINARY')).LoadFromStream(ms);
  Query1.Post;
  Query1.ApplyUpdates;
finally
  ms.free;
end;

Query1.Close;
Query1.SQL.Text:='select * from content order by content_id';
query1.Open();
```

2) **сохранение в блоб из текстового файла** (Англииский текст правильно сохраняется, а русские и грузинские-нет):

```
ID:=Query1.FieldByName('Content_id').asInteger;
OpenDialog1.Execute;

Query1.Close;
Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM content where Content_id=:id';
Query1.Params[0].AsInteger:=ID;
Query1.open;

Query1.Edit;
(Query1.FieldByName('Blob_Binary') as 
TBlobField).LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
Query1.Post;
```

3) **Открыть в memo**:

```
   var
     ms : TMemoryStream;
   begin
     ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     TBlobField(Query1.FieldByName('Blob_Binary')).SaveToStream(ms); //or Blob_Text
     ms.position := 0; 
     memo1.lines.loadfromstream(ms);
   finally
     ms.free;
   end;
```

результат: из бинарного blob-а выводится "1111 Hello i?eaao", а из текстового- только первая буква текста- "1":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или из блоб-ов в memo1 и memo2 выводятся правильно хотя,как выдно из dbMemo1 и dbMemo2, в бд сохранены иероглифы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) **IBExpert:**

```
Update content set Blob_Binary='hello привет გამარჯობა',Blob_Text='hello привет გამარჯობა' where content_id=...
```

записывает в бинарном blob-е кракозябры на месте русских и грузинских букв, а в текстовом- всё правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89643/discussion-on-question-by-basti--------).